# How to add or remove [RequiredAttribute] data annotation at run time on model's properties in .NET Core?

Tags: c#

How can I add or remove a [`[Required]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute?view=netcore-2.2) data annotation on a model property at runtime? I'm using .NET Core MVC 2.2.

Comment: I think that [FastDeepCliner](https://github.com/AlenToma/FastDeepCloner) can help you

Comment: The End user can configure which fields need to mandatory, based on that validation need to be applied for a particular page/view.

Comment: What is the use case for it? Why would you like to add or remove data annotation?